# Wix Run Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, wix

How can I exectute a custom powershell script from a Wix deployment project?  I would like to perform some actions at the end of the install process, such as create a IIS virtual directory.

Comment: Can you run programs? If so, why does `powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy remotesigned -file foo.ps1` not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to change your mind towards the [standard WiX IIsExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_index.htm). It supports creating virtual directories out of the box.